# scroll bar for my data in excel is not working properly

Tags: excel

In the excel template that I am working on there is a scroll bar to change the month. but it is not working properly. when I click to change the month it jumps to the last month (it jumps from January to December. sometimes it works well but sometimes it just jumps). I checked for the format control and everything is ok, but the scroll bar is not functioning well. I hope you guys could help me. can you guys suggest me other ways to change the month other than a scroll bar? I am attaching a screenshot so you guys can understand it better. thanks!
`$B$3= 1` (default)

**here is the screenshot:**
[image: 1]

**here is the screenshot for the VB code:**
[image: 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure what your problem is. Yet, everything seems to work on my end without a problem:

[image]

BTW, your VBA code has nothing to do with the scrollbar and is not required as you can see in the screen-cast (shown above). So, maybe you can share your file with us (upload it some place and provide a download link here) so we can have a look at it. There is probably another problem in that file.

Comment: Thanks man. I will appreciate if you could give me some help. here is the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6oRHD8KdbkyTFNiMlFLVlRWWjA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: In the original template there was no ID column and I added that column by myself. But after adding that column now it shows only 30 days for January. not 31 days. I tried adding a new column but it didnt work.

Comment: I am not quite sure what your problem is. But your file is behaving exactly as mine: if you click on the arrow heads then it is moving one month at a time (from January to February to March to April....) if you click on the scroll-bar then it is moving three month at a time (as indicated on your screenshot where page changer is set to three). There is no annual jump as you seem to experience.

Comment: There are already 31 days in the sheet (to accommodate for January, March and the other months with 31 days). You just have to make sure that there is a macro attached which shows / hides this column (in accordance to the current month).

Comment: but when january is 31 days then the february begins from 2nd day and when i fix the February the January goes again to 30 days! sorry man.. I have been working several days on this templates since I am kinda new to excel I am really confused

Comment: What you are addressing here is a new question and has nothing to do with the problem described in the above post (moving more than one month at a time with the scroll bar). If you have a new question then please post it as such. The problem of moving several months at a time seems to be resolved. Now you need to ensure that the correct columns are hidden / shown in accordance with the current month. For that you need to program a macro (with VBA) to show and hide columns based on the currently selected month. That's a new question / post and you should add your current VBA code for that.

Comment: But you'll need a new approach for this solution. Currently, your VBA code is showing / hiding columns based on a multiple of 31 (as you can see in the code). But that's not possible since not all months have 31 days. So, either you change your sheet setup (the calendar on the sheet) or you make your VBA code much more complex to adjust for each month individually (checking the year, checking for leap years, calculating the months, and then showing / hiding the necessary columns). The latter of the two will require much more VBA code than you currently have.